# Mathematical description of bagel slicing into interlinked tori?

Tags: general-topology

On his blog, MIT professor George W. Hart (http://www.georgehart.com/bagel/bagel.html) depicts decomposing a bagel, i.e., solid torus, into a pair of interlinked solid tori.

I presume this is a known decomposition. Where might one find a mathematical description?

Comment: I first saw this here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3_VydFQmtZ8 and I'm guessing Sequin has published on it (http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~sequin/BIO/rpub.html).

Answer (score 6):

The boundary of one piece of the sliced torus can be parametrized by $$\begin{align*}x(u,v) &= (2+\cos(u+v))\cos u, \\ y(u,v) &= (2+\cos(u+v))\sin u, \\ z(u,v) &= \sin(u+v), \end{align*}$$ for $u \in [0,2\pi)$ and $v \in [0,\pi)$.  The surface of the cut itself can be parametrized by $$\begin{align*}x(u,w) &= (2+w \cos u) \cos u, \\ y(u,w) &= (2+w \cos u) \sin u, \\ z(u,w) &= w \sin u, \end{align*}$$ with $u \in [0,2\pi)$ and $w \in [-1,1]$.  This is a Möbius-like strip with a full twist; a half twist would have been parametrized with $u/2$ instead of $u$ for the trigonometric terms in parentheses as well as the one for $z$.

Pretty pictures to help visualize the way the torus is cut:

[image: Visualization of two halves separating]
[image: Single piece including cut surface]

Comment: I'm a little bit sad that no one seems to like my animations  T_T

Comment: Can you provide an explicit map from the solid torus to the pair of linked solid tori?

Comment: @heropup: I like it! btw, can they be taken apart after slicing creating the moebius -'like' partition? I suppose not.

Answer (score 1):

Carlo Séquin has done work on this.  His publications are at http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~sequin/BIO/rpub.html, 
notably these two:

http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~sequin/PAPERS/2012_JMA_Tori.pdf

http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~sequin/PAPERS/Banff05_SplitTori.pdf

Also, a nice discussion is on Numberphile here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3_VydFQmtZ8

Comment: I didn't find an explicit mathematical description of the torus-splitting there.