# Möbius band and Viviani Frill

Tags: surfaces, parametric, mobius-band

I find a common rule that unites generation of Viviani Frill and the the Möbius Band.

$$ \phi =\theta $$

where $ \phi,\theta $ are spherical coordinates.

Please comment if this way looking at it appeals or otherwise. It has also to do with

bringing in higher dimensionality by conversion of a constant to a parameter/variable.

[VivianiFrill and Möbius Band](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/69459/find-phi-as-function-of-theta-for-villarceau-circle-in-a-torus)

[image: Viviani Frill and Möbius Strip]

[image: MB with u limit inside Torus]

EDIT1:
The adopted first one given here is same as Wiki. May be equivalent embedding by parameter/variable changes? The plot above shows Band inside Torus if 1 > u > -1. Three parametrizations:

$x(u,v)= \left(1+v \cos u\right)\cos u$;
$y(u,v)= \left(1+v \cos u\right)\sin u$;
$z(u,v)= v\sin u $;

Mathworld:

$x(u,v)= \left(1+v \cos \frac{u}{2}\right)\cos u$;
$y(u,v)= \left(1+\,v \cos\frac{u}{2}\right)\sin u$;
$z(u,v)= \,v\sin \frac{u}{2}$;

Wiki:

$x(u,v)= \left(1+\frac{v}{2} \cos \frac{u}{2}\right)\cos u$;
$y(u,v)= \left(1+\frac{v}{2} \cos\frac{u}{2}\right)\sin u$;
$z(u,v)= \frac{v}{2}\sin \frac{u}{2}$;

EDIT2:

[image: Extended u interval MB]

The extended period also shows proper embedding for the parametrization:

$$ [(b + u \cos\theta ) \cos\theta, (b + u \cos\theta) \sin \theta, u \sin\theta] $$

Comment: The new pic (labeled "Moebius band -1 < u < 1") is also not a Mobius band, but rather is a cylinder. You can tell, because it has two boundary components.

Comment: There is only one boundary marked in red, even if extended to $\pm 10 $ . I am afraid, can see no cylinder !

Comment: also, your picture on EDIT2 isn't a Möbius band at all

Comment: In third picturethe leftmost point of your strip is a boundary point; it's at the opposite end of a straight horizontal line (a "ruling") from a red point. If for each red point you walk along the "ruling" to the other end, you'll get a  point you could color green. These form a circle. The red and green circles are the boundary of a topologicalcylinder. In fact, if you label the points in red with values $\theta$ from $0$ to $2\pi$, and "distance from red" along a ruling with values $r$ from $0$ to $1$, then $(\theta, r)$ provide a homeomorphism to the cylinder $S^1 \times [0, 1]$.

Comment: @John Hughes. Thanks for explanation;'ll be back soon :( no images on my PC.

Answer (score 1):

Your picture of a Mobius band on a torus is incorrect...if you trace along the edges of the strip you've drawn, you'll see that it has two disjoint edges.

It CAN'T be a Mobius band, because if it were, then the strip perpendicular to it -- a neighborhood, in the torus, of the centerline --- would also have to be a Mobius strip, because their direct sum is a trivial bundle over the circle. But if there were a Mobius strip embedded in the torus, the torus would be nonorientable.

As for the V-frill and its relation to the M-band: I don't see much in anything that's this strongly coordinate-dependent, esp. when the coordinate system (on the sphere at least) is degenerate at the poles...but maybe I'm just missing something. This seems more like a statement about the cylinder, which admits an almost-everywhere nice map to the sphere (i.e., "contract the two end-circles to points") and an almost-everywhere-nice map to the torus (i.e., "identify the two end circles").

Comment: Thanks much. Let me assimilate this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to a similar topic that I addressed earlier, which includes equations as well as animations.

[Mathematical description of bagel slicing into interlinked tori?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/884063/mathematical-description-of-bagel-slicing-into-interlinked-tori/884088#884088)